# vb.net double openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I need to select 2 file for open them; I want to do that by only one window, so I tryed to build a custom dialog, but I lost drag&drop, rename etc explorer built-in function. Is there a way like show 2 openfiledialog in one window?

Comment: It seems to me that the best way to do this would be with a `TreeView` with checkboxes enabled. Don't try to use the inbuilt dialogues because they're not made for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on a my search I end up that the solution suggested my jmcilhinney is the best compromise between time/effort.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `MultiSelect` property of the OpenFileDialog object to `True`.

Comment: this files can be in different folder, how do you select them both?